# Multitouch on an Android app

Tags: android, multi-touch

Is multitouch available to Android app developers? I've heard its on the new 2.0 version but only seen it accomplished on the internet browser.

Comment: There are a number of applications that employ multitouch: Dolphin Web Browser, and one called "Gallery" which is different than the Android Gallery.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this API here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Basically lets you keep track of more than one pointer at a time.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ThePosey's answer:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

> onTouch() - This returns a boolean to
>   indicate whether your listener
>   consumes this event. The important
>   thing is that this event can have
>   multiple actions that follow each
>   other. So, if you return false when
>   the down action event is received, you
>   indicate that you have not consumed
>   the event and are also not interested
>   in subsequent actions from this event.
>   Thus, you will not be called for any
>   other actions within the event, such
>   as a fingure gesture, or the eventual
>   up action event.